# Can I access to many Youtube channels reports with a only one account?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I manage several Youtube channels, each with their Gmail account and now also associated with a Google+ account.

My question is: I can access, via Youtube Analytics API, to all my Youtube channels reports with a single Google account without having to choose between them? That is, a general account with permissions to access reports on all channels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I link an google+ account with all my YT channels, Could I access to the analytics reports of all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you actually can have these different channels linked under a single Google account.

1) Set up a Google Plus Page for your YouTube account via https://www.youtube.com/account (requires g+ account) *Note: This may overwrite avatar and channel title, and may change your YouTube display name to whatever you set your Page Title to be.*

2) Your personal g+ account will be the owner of this Google plus page.

3) Repeat for other accounts, setting up their own google plus pages.

4) You can add your main personal g+ account (if you have one for each unique gmail) as a "manager" of these other pages, giving a single login access to the pages (and therefore all the associated YouTube accounts) via the drop down "switch acocunts" on YouTube (top right drop down)

5) After a page is old enough (2 weeks?) you can change owners so your main g+ page owns the page. Not necessary but helps consolidate + lets you abandon other personal g+ accounts.

Let me know if you're able to follow that. There are benefits to doing this with only a single channel. You won't be able to see "combined" analytics but you can switch accounts much, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides the youtube channel report in range. But when used with google php library it get hooked in a "User login required Error!"

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=views&dimensions=day&_h=3&

Is there any way i can access the channel analytics report in youtube V3 same as like in v3

http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&id=UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ&_h=10&